# node.js to upload image using multer shows undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, multer

Here I'm trying to upload files from 2 different file inputs, I'm able to upload it to the front-end but in the backend it remains `undefined`. Tried a couple of things but didn't work.

html:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" file-model = "file1"/>
<input type="file" name="file2" file-model = "file2"/>
<button  ng-click = "uploadFile()">UPLOAD FILES</button>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('fileModel', ['$parse',
  function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
])
```

service:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('fileUpload', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file1', file);
      fd.append('file2', file);
      $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }
      })
    }
  }
]);
```

controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', '$http',
      function($scope, fileUpload, $http) {
        $scope.uploadFile = function() {
          var file1 = $scope.file1;
          var file2 = $scope.file2;
          console.log('file is ');
          console.dir(file1);
          console.dir(file2);

          var uploadUrl = '/upload';
          fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl({
            file1, file2
          }, uploadUrl);
        };
```

server:

```
function upload(req,res){
  console.log(req.files.file1);
}
```

Comment: What does  `console.dir(file1);` and `console.dir(file2);` prints?

Comment: yes it does prints

Comment: I mean what does they print? What are the output?

Comment: this is what my browser console reads

    File
    lastModified
   :
   1446532932000
   lastModifiedDate
   :
   Tue Nov 03 2015 12:12:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
   name
   :
  "pic03.jpg"
   size
  :
   76606
   type
   :
   "image/jpeg"
   webkitRelativePath
   :
   ""
   __proto__
   :
   Blob

Comment: Ankit verma ensieg??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one case of file can't be find in server side at nodejs ie you can provide the multerobject in
 `/api/v1/uploadfile": [{
                method: "POST",
                action: controllers.advertController.videoUpload,
                middleware: [multipartMiddleware],
                views: {
                    json: views.jsonView
                }
            }],`

```
global.multipartMiddleware = multipart();
```

At server side code use multipartMiddleware at middleware of request.

> Controller (in this you pass correct parameter to service)

`var file ={}
file.file1=file1;
file.file2=file2;
fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);`

> Service (if you want to upload multiple file at a time use loop)

```
angular.module('myApp').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
       var fd = new FormData();
       fd.append('file1', file.file1);
       fd.append('file2', file.file2);
       $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
       })
    }
 }]);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it helped me. I just had to change the service code as u directed :)